# How do I go about writing a Linux driver for an LCD screen?

Tags: c, embedded, linux-device-driver

I'll start by explaining what I'm looking to do.

I have a BeagleBone Black running Ubuntu 13.04, and this [TFT LCD w/touchscreen](http://www.adafruit.com/products/335).

There is a library for the touchscreen that can be used with an Arduino to draw primitive graphics and text on the screen. However, instead of just adapting this library to run on the BeagleBone, I would like to write a driver for this LCD that would allow me to display a GUI created with Qt.

According to Qt's website, embedded Linux applications are written directly the frame buffer.

I have been using [this book](http://oreilly.com/openbook/linuxdrive3/book/) for reference when writing drivers, but I have not been able to find much information about how the frame buffer works and how it would interact with the LCD driver.

My questions:

1. Do I have to implement my own frame buffer in order to use Qt to draw a GUI on this screen?
2. If so, will I have to implement a separate driver for the screen to interact with the frame buffer, or would the frame buffer also handle sending the data to the screen?
3. Can anyone suggest any examples or reference materials on developing drivers for LCD screens?

Comment: For the specific TFT LCD mentioned by you, it is programmable via SPI.   So you should hook it up to the beaglebone via the GPIO pin, and program the LCD via SPI programming:   http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nds2x3Zv1r8, http://www.adafruit.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=27704

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but my question is not how to communicate with the screen directly, I am aware that SPI is one way that I can communicate with it.  I am specifically asking about how to use it as a framebuffer device so that an application written with Qt can draw a GUI to it.

Comment: I am looking for something similar. Can you help?